# Binary Search Iterative and Recursive with tuple (python)

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search

I am trying to create a binary search (both iterative and recursive) with the parameters being (tuple, int). I really want to understand it more because I thought I understood the code logically as is, but apparently not.

The iterative code (isMemberI) is giving me correct results half of the time, and then randomly incorrect so I don't know what is causing this. I am getting no errors, just the wrong answer sometimes.

The recursive code gives me errors sometimes, and then works probably ¼ of my test cases. When I try the following, I am getting these errors:

```
>>> isMemberR((1, 2, 3, 3, 4), 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    isMemberR((1, 2, 3, 3, 4), 4)
  File "/Users/alyssakelley/Documents/p93_binsearch.py", line 127, in     isMemberR
    return isMemberR(aseq[midpoint + 1], target)
  File "/Users/alyssakelley/Documents/p93_binsearch.py", line 117, in isMemberR
    if len(aseq) == 0:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

>>> isMemberR('aeiou', 'y')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    isMemberR('aeiou', 'y')
  File "/Users/alyssakelley/Documents/p93_binsearch.py", line 127, in isMemberR
    return isMemberR(aseq[midpoint + 1], target)
  File "/Users/alyssakelley/Documents/p93_binsearch.py", line 127, in isMemberR
    return isMemberR(aseq[midpoint + 1], target)
IndexError: string index out of range


>>> isMemberR((1, 3, 5, 7), 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    isMemberR((1, 3, 5, 7), 4)
  File "/Users/alyssakelley/Documents/p93_binsearch.py", line 125, in isMemberR
    return isMemberR(aseq[:midpoint], target)
  File "/Users/alyssakelley/Documents/p93_binsearch.py", line 127, in isMemberR
   return isMemberR(aseq[midpoint + 1], target)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

**Here is my code:**

```
def isMemberI(aseq, target):
    first = 0
    last = len(aseq) - 1
    found = False

    while first < last:
        midpoint = (first + last) // 2
        if aseq[midpoint] == target:
            found = True

        else:
            if target < aseq[midpoint]:
                last = midpoint - 1
            else:
                first = midpoint + 1
    return found 

def isMemberR(aseq, target):
    if len(aseq) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        midpoint = len(aseq) // 2
        if aseq[midpoint] == target:
            return True
        else:
            if target < aseq[midpoint]:
                return isMemberR(aseq[:midpoint], target)
            else:
                return isMemberR(aseq[midpoint + 1], target)
```

Test Cases that I am trying and results I **EXPECT** :

```
>>> isMemberI((1, 2, 3, 3, 4), 4)
True

>>> isMemberI((1, 2, 3, 3, 4), 2)
True

>>> isMemberI('aeiou', 'i')
True

>>> isMemberI('aeiou', 'y')
False

>>> isMemberI((1, 3, 5, 7), 4)
False

>>> isMemberI((23, 24, 25, 26, 27), 5)
False

>>> isMemberI((0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 8), 4)
True

>>> isMemberI((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 3)
True

>>> isMemberI((1, 3), 1)
True

>>> isMemberI((2, 10), 10)
True

>>> isMemberI((99, 100), 101)
False

>>> isMemberI((42,), 42)
True

>>> isMemberI((43,), 44)
False

>>> isMemberI((), 99)
False
'''
```

Comment: Is `aseq[midpoint + 1]` in `isMemberR(aseq[midpoint + 1], target)` `aseq`uence? It's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the last function call is passing a value at index `midpoint+1` instead of tuple .

**Errors Explained**

***IndexError***: tuple index out of range , this occurs when len of tuple is 1 and `midpoint+1` is `1` which is out of range as there is only one element

***TypeError***: object of type 'int' has no len() , thats when `int` is passed in last line as first arguement to `isMemberR`

```
def isMemberR(aseq, target):
    if len(aseq) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        midpoint = len(aseq) // 2
        if aseq[midpoint] == target:
            return True
        else:
            if target < aseq[midpoint]:
                return isMemberR(aseq[:midpoint], target)
            else:
                return isMemberR(aseq[midpoint+1:], target)
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you for explaining that :D